# How can i create a gridview with no data on loading?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

So i have an standard `gridview` created by `gii`, it is connected to a `mysql` database that already have some records, it works perfect but i need that when the page is loaded, no data should be displayed on the view, it only should be displayed after a search is done on any of the fields.

How can i setup a gridview that on load no data is displayed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (or a variation with several search parameters) in your `ModelSearch.php`

```
if($this->your_search_attribute == '') $query->andFilterWhere(['id' => 0]);
```

Do not know if there's a easier more yii-like way..

Comment: That worked at least for the attribute i added, is a good guideline